# Jasmine JS understanding global context

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a question about how Jasmine actually processes global context. In the api docs methods like `beforeEach(),afterEach(), etc` are described as global. Therefore, they are called without the `.` operator as Jasmine recognizes them.

I have the following simple class:

```
export class VoteComponent { 
  totalVotes = 0; 

  upVote() { 
    this.totalVotes++;
  }

  downVote() { 
    this.totalVotes--;
  }
}
```

And to test the following spec, which works fine:

```
import { VoteComponent } from './vote.component';

describe('VoteComponent', () => {
  let Votes :VoteComponent;
 beforeEach(()=>{
       Votes = new VoteComponent();
 })
  it('Upvotes', () => {
        Votes.upVote();
        expect(Votes.totalVotes).toBe(1);
  });

  it('Downvotes', () => {
        Votes.downVote();
        expect(Votes.totalVotes).toBe(-1);
  });
});
```

However, if I change my spec to look like this:

```
 // let Votes :VoteComponent;
 beforeEach(()=>{
       let Votes = new VoteComponent();
 })
```

I get the following error:

> Chrome 67.0.3396 (Windows 10.0.0) VoteComponent Upvotes FAILED
>           ReferenceError: Votes is not defined

I don't get why this is. beforeEach() is a global context function, and gets called before each spec. But even so within the spec `Votes` is not recognized unless instantiated outside of the beforeEach().

Why is this? I am using Angular-6, Karma 1.7 and Jasmine 2.9

Comment: `let` has block scope.

Comment: Right... but the block is in global context. So shouldn't it still be accessible? Given that it runs before each spec?

Comment: No. The `beforeEach` function is global but that doesn't make anything declared within its scope automatically global.

Comment: Thanks HDK that actually makes alot more sense when I see someone else saying it. I'm new to Jasmine and I'm working through a udemy class but I got stuck on this concept and had a feeling that wasn't how it worked. But I couldnt find anything that explicitly said so.